# Root-Restricted-Docker Image

Tags: docker, security, hardening

I have a use case, i have to give a docker image to one of my client, but no one should able to see what is inside the container, moreover should not able to copy anything from the Container, is it possible, if possible can you please guide me how to do..

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: It's not possible.

Comment: Thank you David Maze, 
but i came across some gosu utility, just giving a try, let us see how it goes.

Comment: As the linked questions suggest, you can't prevent someone from `docker run -u root --entrypoint /bin/sh your-image` if the image has a shell at all.